# BIRT report - Create different footers for different pages in a group list

Tags: javascript, eclipse, reporting, birt

I am currently working on BIRT v4.8. 
I have created a list and inside the list, I have applied grouping and a page break for that particular grouping.

[image]

I want to display the report in the following format.

Suppose, if there are 3 pages in the group, for the first two pages, there is one footer and for the last page, there is a separate footer.

The following two images shows the first 2 pages of the grouping which has one footer

[image]
[image]

The image below refers to the last page of the grouping which has a separate footer.

[image]

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the data into a new table, this will allow you to have a second footer which is different. You would need to bind the data from the second table to your parameter for this to work correctly. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIDog.jpg)